# How to match a path while traversing a tree structure

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, traversal

I have a tree like structure that contains Parents and Childrens. There is no limit on number of children a parent can have. Each node in the tree have some specific set of properties.

I have a list like structure that represents a path. Each node in the path has the same set of properties with some specific values. The first node in the path is always the same as root of the tree mentioned above.

I want to traverse the Tree starting from the Root and check if the path exists in the tree by comparing the properties of Node on Tree with the properties of Node on path. Meanwhile keeping the record of TreeNodes that has satisfied the matching condition. Plz note, TreeNode and PathNode are totally different types, they just have some properties that are common, e.g. Name, Id, Location etc.

The simplest approach I could think of is to have a recursive call to traverse the children of tree and for each level of tree I compare the next Node in the path, but I am not sure if there is any easy way of doing it. I will have to implement it in C#, so is there any specific structure or library available to do it. Any language specific solution would be really helpful, otherwise I can translate it to C#, just need to get the idea of how it should be designed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve the problem abstractly.

A path is either:

- an empty path, or
- a path fragment (the head of the path) followed by a path (the tail of the path)

A tree is:

- a node followed by a list of zero or more trees (the children).

Note that in this definition there is no empty tree. You said there was always a root.

We now define a predicate "match" as follows.

- A path fragment may match a tree node. How it matches is up to you.
- The empty path matches all trees.
- Suppose we have a head followed by a tail, and a node followed by children. The path matches the tree if and only if (1) the head matches the node, and (2) either the tail is empty, or there exists at least one child that matches with the tail.

This sketch should be plenty detailed enough to write an implementation in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the extension below to traverse recursive Directory/File tree. It might not be your exact case but sounds similar. I hope the code helps.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TValue, string>> TraverseValuesWithPaths<T, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector, Func<T, IEnumerable<TValue>> valueSelector, Func<T, string> childNameSelector, Func<TValue, string> valueNameSelector, string pathStart = null, string separator = null)
    {
        Func<string, string, string> pathCombine = (a, b) => string.Concat(a, separator, b);

        var stack = new Stack<Tuple<T, string>>(items.Select(i => new Tuple<T, string>(i, pathCombine(pathStart, childNameSelector(i)))));

        while (stack.Any())
        {
            var next = stack.Pop();

            foreach (var child in childSelector(next.Item1))
            {
                stack.Push(new Tuple<T, string>(child, pathCombine(next.Item2, childNameSelector(child))));
            }

            var values = valueSelector(next.Item1);

            if (values != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    yield return new Tuple<TValue, string>(value, pathCombine(next.Item2, valueNameSelector(value)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
// produce flat list of files and path 
var allFiles = folders.TraverseValuesWithPaths(folder => folder.Folders, folder => folder.Files, folder => folder.Name, file => file.Name, "\"", "\"");
```